# Query to find No. of employees earning maximum salary

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find the number of employees in a table that earn exactly the maximum salary of all the employees in the table called tblPerson.

```
Select Max(x.[No of Employees]) as Number, x.Salary as Salary  
from
(
Select      Count(Id) as [No of Employees], Salary
from        tblPerson
Group by    Salary 
Having      Salary = MAX(Salary)
)x
where x.[No of Employees]=3
```

Now I know this is a kind of long and complex way of doing it, but I was trying to do it using a derived table. But I am getting the error:

"Column 'x.Salary' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

My question is, why am I getting this particular error since the main query is a simple Select statement with a where clause. Isn't it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. Every answer helped me. However, I think I found a pretty simple way to do it:

```
Select      top 1 Count(Id) as [No of Employees], salary
from        tblPerson
Group by    Salary
Order by    [No of Employees] DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `order by salary desc`? The way you have it would give you the "most popular" salary.

Comment: @Steve Lovell: No. The objective wasn't to find the salary which is earned by maximum number of people (most popular salary) as you said. The objective was to find how many people earn the maximum salary of all the people in the company.

Comment: One of us is confused. It sounds like we agree about what you want, but then I still think the code `order by [No of Employees] Desc` can't be right.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, aggregate functions work only with other aggregate functions or grouped by columns.

Why? Because an aggregate function needs to know the set of values to do calculation with. 
In you case, the max() will want to use all the data available for the calculation and display a single result (single row) and the other column will want to be displayed row by row. So there's a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from tblPerson where salary=(select max(salary) from tblPerson)
```

Comment: Nopes.. doesn't work sir. Please look at my comment above in reply to the above answer

Comment: Check your outer query "Select Max(x.[No of Employees]) as Number, x.Salary as Salary from x where x.[No of Employees]=3 ".  You are trying to calculate Max of number of employees and with that you are trying to get the salary. If you are using Max function which is an aggregate function, then other expression in select statement should be a group_by expression. Refer: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php

Comment: Yeah right. I get it now. I mean the concept. But I still can't figure out the solution to do it :(

Comment: Also your where clause is wrong, as you are limiting aggregation of Max(outer query) for the salary group(defined in inner query) which is having number of employees as 3.

Comment: I think regarding the where clause, even if I do something like this:

where x.[No of Employees]= (Select Max(x.[No of Employees] from x), it doesn't compile because it says invalid object x

Comment: If you are trying to find number of employee having maximum salary, then you can go for `Select      Count(Id) as [No of Employees], Salary
from        tblPerson
Group by    Salary 
Having      Salary = MAX(Salary)`. If you want number of employees havin maximum salary then this will work `select count(*) from tblPerson where salary=(select max(salary) from tblPerson)`

Comment: I am trying to find both: the number of employees having maximum salary and what that salary is. How do I do that? The output should be something like 3, 3400 which implies 3 employees earn 3400 which is the max salary of all the employees say

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because 'max' is an aggregation, while you have nothing to aggregate the number by.

```
Select Max(x.[No of Employees]) as Number, x.Salary as Salary  
from
(
Select      Count(Id) as [No of Employees], Salary
from        tblPerson
Group by    Salary 
Having      Salary = MAX(Salary)
)x
---------
Group by Salary -- all other items in your select statement
---------
where x.[No of Employees]=3
```

however, you can also use a temporary table or variable to find the persons.
To solve this via a variable, you could do the following

```
declare @maxSalary Decimal
set @maxSalary = (Select max(salary) from tblperson) --insert the max value into a variable
```

Then either aggregate the persons (or do some other logic):

```
Select ID from tblperson where salary = @maxSalary
```

The reason for not using a group by is that using a variable is more efficient, as you search the table instead of aggregating over it.

Comment: I didn't get your explanation for why am I getting the error. You said max is an aggregation, which is 100% correct. But then I think what you said isn't clear. because if I just do this:

Select Max(x.[No of Employees]) as Number, x.Salary as Salary  
from
(
Select      Count(Id) as [No of Employees], Salary
from        tblPerson
Group by    Salary 
Having      Salary = MAX(Salary)
)x

, this works and gives the number of employees earning the maximum salary

Comment: And the way you did it is absolutely correct. You basically broke the query into 2 parts where you first find the max salary and then find the number of poeple earning that salary. But I want to learn how to do it without breaking. So..

Comment: the SQL logic for aggregating is that you should either have a single value you aggregate (like Select max(salary) from tblperson)
If you don't, you need to group every other value, with is not getting aggregated, hence we group by salary.

Thus, you get the error because it dosn't know how to aggregate salary, as it is not grouped by it, and expects some sort of aggregation method (or grouping logic).

to your second comment, see the first code example i posted, it should work - i only wanted to highlight the grouping statement you needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a CTE (RESULT), and using DENSE_RANK function, get the highest salary, together with the EmployeeID's.
The first row of the RESULT table will give the highest salary.
Using the aggregate function COUNT, get the number of Employees with the highest Salary.

```
with RESULT (EmployeeID, Salary, DenseRank) as  
     (select EmployeeID, Salary,   
      DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DenseRank
      from Employee)

select TOP 1 Salary,  
              (select COUNT(EmployeeID)  
               from Employee  
               where Salary = (select TOP 1 Salary)  
                               from RESULT  
                                where DenseRank = 1)
               )  
 from RESULT  
 where DenseRank = 1;
```

Comment: Formatting for the purpose of making things clearer is obviously not your strength.